# Problems with incrementing 2-d java array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, increment

I've been trying to solve this one exercise for three days but I won't get it. The idea is to create matrix that increments with one. The program asks for the size of rows and columns and then creates the matrix.

I give a example of the expected result:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
```

Here is what I get:

```
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
```

And here is my code:

```
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                        (System.in));

        // User enters row and column size of the 2D array.
        System.out.print ("Input row size: ");
        int ro = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        System.out.print ("Input column size: ");
        int co = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.println ("   Array is " + ro + "x" + co);

        // Creating a 2D array.
        int[][] a = new int[ro][co];

        // User enters values, which are put into the array. 
        // This is the part where the code fails.
        System.out.print ("The matrix has " + ro*co + " integer values");
        System.out.println (" (one per line): ");
        for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length; c++) {
                a [r][c] +=1;
            }

        // Printing the matrix
        System.out.println ("Matrix:");
        for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length; c++)
                System.out.print (a[r][c] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a variable outside of the loop to increment, e.g.

```
int incr = 0;
```

Within the loop, do this

```
a [r][c] = ++incr;
```

Currently, you are incrementing each element in the array which is initally `0`, so `0+1` always ends up as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop simply increments the array by one. Since all of the array elements start as zero, all of it is incremented by 1, thus your result. Try including a variable outside the loop like:

```
int i = 0;
```

then change the line inside the loop to something like

```
i++;
a[r][c] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment outside the loop, because `Array` is an object and data member of any object gets default value so it will assign `0` to each element of array.

```
int inc = 0;
```

and within the loop

```
a[r][c]=inc++;
```

Comment: Note: when using `inc++` (as opposed to `++inc`) the first element in the matrix will be `0`. (`++inc` increments before assignment, `inc++` afterwards)

Comment: it depends on you what you want as a first element, if you want 1 then use pre-increment and if you want 0 use post-increment.. :)

Comment: Of course :) just added this comment as additional info because the example in the question starts with 1. It was rather targeted at Java beginners potentially reading this, not at you :)

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // User enters row and column size of the 2D array.
    System.out.print("Input row size: ");
    int ro = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    System.out.print("Input column size: ");
    int co = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    System.out.println("   Array is " + ro + "x" + co);

    // Creating a 2D array.
    int[][] a = new int[ro][co];

    // User enters values, which are put into the array.
    // This is the part where the code fails.
    System.out.print("The matrix has " + ro * co + " integer values");
    System.out.println(" (one per line): ");
    //For incremental purpose
    int counter = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length; c++) {
            a[r][c] = ++counter;
        }

    // Printing the matrix
    System.out.println("Matrix:");
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length; c++)
            System.out.print(a[r][c] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```